# a:hover z-index not working...Very Weird

Tags: css

I have coded concentric circles as my menu bar and I am trying to use a:hover to effect the z-index of each circle. I have given each circle a display:block; property so that each circle is a link itself (not just the text within). Unfortunately, the a:hover z-index command isn't working at all. I have read the other threads on stackoverflow relating to this but none of those solutions seem to be my problem. Does anyone know what is going on?

Here is the CSS:

```
a:hover{ 
  z-index:90000;
}

#container {
   position: relative;
   width: 500px;
   height:500px;

}

#circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: block;
    z-index: 5;
 }

#circle1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 85%;
    height: 85%;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-top: 7.5%;
    margin-left: 7.5%;
    z-index: 6;
}


#circle2{
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: #0C9;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #00F;
    display: block;
    z-index: 7;
}


#circle3{
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #C33;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url(Sunset.jpg);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100px;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="circle"></div>
<a style="display:block" a href="p1.html">
<div id="circle1">PHOTOGRAPHS</div>
</a>
<div id="circle2"></div>
<a style="display:block" a href="p1.html">
<div id="circle3">BED TIME</div>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The element that you want to hover to put `z-index:90000` on it needs to be relative or absolute. Otherwise it's not working.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying for but it seems to me as an outer circle comes to the top it will block smaller inner circles from being hoverable. Either way as previous comment said you will need to make the anchors position relative or absolute or add the z-index to the div inside the anchor. Also because style sheets cascade you will need an important on the hover. https://jsfiddle.net/r4f68tu6/ I also highly recommend you read this: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: Thank you for the article on Z-index. It is very enlightening. However, I have positioned each of the circles as position: absolute. I am trying to have each circle cover up the circles that are smaller than the one being hovered on by the mouse. Here is my non-functioning page to see the circle construction: http://informedspectacle.org/

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you for your help!!